# VSS/VC++ integration: requires checking out SLN/VCPROJ

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-sourcesafe

Using VSS integration with VC++ 2005, every time I want to bind a project to use the integration it seems to demand I check out the SLN/VCPROJ files so it can add source control data to those files.

That seems screwy, why should the VCS require putting metadata in my files? When I've used other VCS integration this hasn't happened.

Is it possible to simply enable integration without doing this (we have to account for any commits performed)?

*and no, getting rid of VSS isn't a option!*

Answer (score 0):

The vcproj files (and sometimes the sln files too) contain the database and path to which you bind the project. Those entries look something like that:

```
<SccProjectName>"$/MyProject.root/MyProject", CAAAAAAA</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>.</SccLocalPath>
<SccProvider>MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe</SccProvider>
```

So to bind your project Visual Studio needs to edit the vcproj file. It's just how it works and there's no way to change that.

This has the side effect that it when you branch a project, you need to remember to edit the branched vcproj and sln files, and update them to point to the new branch.